# knitr and make fail to make PDF: sh: kpsewhich: command not found

Tags: r, pdf, makefile, latex, knitr

I have the code below in `minimal.Rnw`, which is on my desktop:

```
<<load, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE,cache=FALSE>>=

options(digits=2)

opts_chunk$set(eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, cache = TRUE, dpi=300, dev = "pdf", fig.width=4.2, fig.height=3.7)


@

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Required to insert dummy text


\begin{document}

\section{Header}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


\end{document}
```

When I ran the code below, `knitr`/`make` converted `minimal.Rnw` into a PDF:

```
knit(input = "~/Desktop/minimal.Rnw", output = "~/Desktop/minimal.tex"); setwd("~/Desktop/"); system(paste0("make '-fMakefile' .pdf"))
```

But this code now gives the error below, and a PDF isn't made:

```
processing file: ~/Desktop/minimal.Rnw
  |................................                                 |  50%
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: ~/Desktop/minimal.tex

    [1] "~/Desktop/minimal.tex"
    Warning message:
    In test_latex_pkg("framed", system.file("misc", "framed.sty", package = "knitr")) :
      unable to find LaTeX package 'framed'; will use a copy from knitr
    sh: kpsewhich: command not found
    xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Here's the output from `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11 (unknown)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] tidyr_0.3.1           cowplot_0.5.0         readxl_0.1.0          boot_1.3-16           mgcv_1.8-6           
 [6] nlme_3.1-120          stringi_0.4-1         pavo_0.5-1            rgl_0.95.1201         GGally_0.5.0         
[11] moult_1.4             geosphere_1.3-13      broom_0.3.6           testthat_0.9.1        pscl_1.4.9           
[16] MASS_7.3-40           repmis_0.4.2          english_1.0-1         dplyr_0.4.1           scales_0.2.5         
[21] stargazer_5.1         combinat_0.0-8        xlsx_0.5.7            xlsxjars_0.6.1        rJava_0.9-6          
[26] gdata_2.13.3          tuneR_1.2.1           GPArotation_2014.11-1 MuMIn_1.13.4          psych_1.5.4          
[31] effects_3.0-3         openNLP_0.2-4         extrafont_0.17        car_2.0-25            raster_2.3-40        
[36] Hmisc_3.15-0          Formula_1.2-1         survival_2.38-1       lattice_0.20-31       maptools_0.8-36      
[41] ggmap_2.4             ggplot2_1.0.1         rgdal_0.9-2           formatR_1.2           lme4_1.1-7           
[46] Rcpp_0.11.5           Matrix_1.2-0          rgeos_0.3-8           sp_1.1-0              knitr_1.11           
[51] lubridate_1.3.3       stringr_0.6.2         plyr_1.8.2            reshape2_1.4.1        gam_1.12             
[56] foreach_1.4.2        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] pbkrtest_0.4-2      RColorBrewer_1.1-2  httr_0.6.1          R.cache_0.10.0      tools_3.2.0         rpart_4.1-9        
 [7] lazyeval_0.1.10     DBI_0.3.1           colorspace_1.2-6    openNLPdata_1.5.3-1 nnet_7.3-9          mnormt_1.5-2       
[13] extrafontdb_1.0     chron_2.3-45        quantreg_5.11       SparseM_1.6         NLP_0.1-6           digest_0.6.8       
[19] foreign_0.8-63      minqa_1.2.4         R.utils_2.0.2       jpeg_0.1-8          maps_2.3-9          gtools_3.4.2       
[25] acepack_1.3-3.3     R.oo_1.19.0         magrittr_1.5        munsell_0.4.2       proto_0.3-10        R.methodsS3_1.7.0  
[31] RJSONIO_1.3-0       parallel_3.2.0      mapproj_1.2-2       rcdd_1.1-8          rjson_0.2.15        codetools_0.2-11   
[37] magic_1.5-6         evaluate_0.8        latticeExtra_0.6-26 data.table_1.9.4    png_0.1-7           nloptr_1.0.4       
[43] RgoogleMaps_1.2.0.7 Rttf2pt1_1.3.3      gtable_0.1.2        reshape_0.8.5       assertthat_0.1      geometry_0.3-5     
[49] signal_0.7-4        iterators_1.0.7     memoise_0.2.1       cluster_2.0.1
```

Comment: What happens if you add \usepackage{framed} after the \usepackage{lipsum} command?  The error message suggests doing that.

Comment: Adding `\usepackage{framed}` after the `\usepackage{lipsum}` command didn't change anything